# How to run Jenkins for a specified time?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I want to run a script in Jenkins for 10 hours. Is that possible ? 
My script length is approximately 55 mins. I have now scheduled it to run every hour.So it keeps running every hour.(and never stops!!)

But is there a way to make to run for a specified time,say 10 hours, and then automatically stop? Instead of scheduling, I want it to specify for how long this 55 min script should run continuously,  and then stop automatically.

So if I start a build at 8am and say run for 3 hours, it should keep running till 11am and then stop.

Comment: Your question is not clear. How is it possible to run your script for 10 hrs when you are only saying that the script runs for only 55 mins. From your statement, the best guess i can make is that you want to schedule/cron your build but you have also mentioned that you don't want to schedule. Please clarify.

Comment: I want to specify something like "run for 10 hours" and it should run this 55 min script continuously for 10 hours and stop.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve that with a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) triggered build.

For example a job with `H 8-10/1 * * *` should run every hour between 8 and 10:59.

Take a look at the Jenkins help beside the SCM Trigger.

Comment: Thanks. I want to make this build parametrized and the user can specify the duration(say 3 hours) as the parameter. I want to read this '3' in my java code.I know how to create a parametrized build,but how to read the parameter value in my script? (written in java)

Comment: Got it :P I have a parameter called "Duration". I can access it in java using-> System.getenv("Duration"); Thanks :)

Comment: Tried what u suggested.It ran only once! I expected it to run every hour between 8 and 10.(Ran at 8, did not run at 9)

Comment: I removed the brackets. They were syntactically wrong. Try the format `H 8-10/1 * * *`.

Comment: Great! Looks like this is going to work, though it doesn't allow me to set a time like H 23-11/1 * * * which means start at 11pm and end at 11am!

Comment: Also, I asked a related question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419494/running-a-java-code-repeatedly-for-a-given-duration-in-jenkins